# Find rows matching values from array

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have a form where user select one or more checkboxes like this:

```
{!! Form::Label('faults', 'Please select one of the following that best describes your device') !!}
                                            <div class="form-group">                                            
                                                @foreach($faults as $fault)
                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                    <span><i class="fa fa-question-circle" rel="popover" data-content="{{$fault->fault_tooltip}}"></i></span>
                                                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                                                    <input id="faults" type="checkbox" name="faults[]" value="{{$fault->id}}">{{$fault->fault}}
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                @endforeach
                                            </div>
```

Now in my controller I am getting the input for faults like this:

```
$faults = Input::get('faults');
```

This returns something an array contining the ID's for each fault like this:

```
    array:2 [▼
  0 => "37"
  1 => "36"
]
```

I need to loop through the array and find each row in my faults table matching each id from the array and get other values like $fault->name and $fault->price.

I know this is pretty easy but I am starting with coding and I can't get my head around.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$slectedFaults = Input::get('faults');
```

if you have faults model in \App\ directory then do by following

```
$faults = Faults::whereIn('id',$slectedFaults)->get();
```

or do by foloowing way

```
 $faults = App\DB::table('faults')->whereIn('id',$slectedFaults)->get();
```

$faults have data selected from your database, then do the rest

```
$nameArray = [];
foreach($faults as $fault) {
  $nameArray[] = $fault->name;
  //do your thing here
}
print_r($nameArray); //it will print all fault names
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `Faults` model? if so:

```
$faults = Faults::findMany(Input::get('faults'));

foreach($faults as $fault) {
   //do your thing here
}
```

Otherwise with a table:

```
$faults = DB::table('faults')
  ->select()
  ->whereIn('id',Input::get('faults'))
  ->get();

foreach($faults as $fault) {
   //do your thing here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding that quick! That works but if I try to echo $fault_name (inside the loop:  $fault_name = $fault->name;) I only get 1 fault, but the user selected two.

Comment: if you do `dd($faults)` before the for loop which/how many faults do you see?